# 2008 SSRS What kind of report type and how to properly group data?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008

I am coming from Crystal Reports and trying to replicate what would seem to be a fairly simple report in SSRS 2008, but I am having trouble determining what type of base report style I need, and how to achieve properly nested grouping of my data.

I have watched a bunch of tutorial videos on YouTube, searched google, and experimented with SSRS based on what I have been able to find online, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

```
I have a list of songs associated with each Album Id
The songs can either be Type 1 (Track A) or Type 2 (Track B)
The report results are first grouped by the Album Id (Group Header #1) and then grouped by Song Type (Group Header #2)
There is a new page or page break after unique album id (Group Footer #1) 
I have attached the design example in Crystal Reports and also the Sample PDF created when printing the report.
```

[image: crystal reports design example]
[image: sample pdf of how data is grouped and displayed]

I am hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "report type"? As in Tablix or Matrix? The above data appears to be multiple Tablix datasets, the first 2 with Page groupings.

Comment: Or maybe it's one big dataset with 2 page groupings? One on Artist and another on AlbumName?

Comment: Also, if you are moving to SQL Server, i suggest a more recent version than 2008. 2008 has less than 2 months of support left, so i would recommend looking at more recent versions.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I am sorry I should have specified in my post that this is what I was trying to determine if my report should be a Tablix, Matrix, or List type to achieve the example above.

Comment: The way I have the data currently is one big dataset with 2 groupings one on Album Id, and one by the song type. Song type basically represents whether the song is on Track A or Track B. I am technically on SQL Server 2000, and moving to 2008, and then I have to get to 2016. I am having to move mountains right now just to get from 2000 to 2008.

Comment: Personally i would get the data to 2008, and then straight to 2016. There are changes to the deployment methods (again) between 2008 and 2016, so if you design the reports and then go to 2016 you're going to need to do so again. As 2000 is way out of support, and 2008 is about to be, that should be your priority really. Get the data to the end goal (2016) and then worry about the report in 2016.

Comment: @Larnu I appreciate your honest assessment, and I totally agree with you. Out of curiosity, I was planning on using the reports as standalone reports. Would a standalone report created in 2008 be able to access 2016 data?

Comment: SSRS uses OLEDB to access data from SQL Server, so yes, a report deployed on an SSRS 2008 instance could access data on SQL Server 2016.

Comment: @Larnu Conversely, I should be able to design in report builder 2016 and access 2008 data, which allows me to move towards both goals! Thanks for helping me get on the right path!

Comment: I've used SSDT to access data on old servers multiple times, no issues with doing that. He'll, you could probably build the reports on 2016 and access the 2000 instance (probably)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008 R2, the options in SSRS changed quite a bit. So as pointed out in comments, design the reports in 2008 R2 or more recent version of SQL server/BIDS to get at this.

If creating this report, I would start with a blank report in a recent version of BIDS, and add the data source, then data set, then drag a table onto the design surface. I would drag the Artist name to the "Row Groups" sub-pane of the design window to create a grouping based on Artist. Then I would create a calculated field in the data set that is a concatenation of album name and side. So I could then drag that field into "Row Groups" underneath the Artist group. Right clicking on these groups will let you add rows and headers for the groups to insert the dynamic and static data you are working with.

You can choose Group Properties and indicate that a page break should be inserted between every instance of the Artist group.